# Editing Carets train function

Tags: r, r-caret

this isn't a specific coding issue I'm having, I am just looking for guidance.

I'm using the Caret package to train a `nnet` model and I want to edit the way in which the model is trained and optimised.

According to the documentation, the `train()` function takes the following form:

```
for each parameter set do 
  for each resampling iteration do
    hold out specific samples 
    fit the model
    predict the hold-out samples 
  end
  calculate average
```

From this I can gauge that the training set supplied in the functions argument is split into a train+validation set depending on the sampling method chosen (cv, repeatedcv etc).

I'm wondering if it's possible to maybe adjust the above process of holding out a sample from the training set, and instead supply the function with an additional sample set (validation set) to perform the evaluation on.

I've looked through the source code of the `train` and `trainControl` function but am having a hard time figuring out where the hold out samples are calculated.

If possible, would someone be able to point me to the relevant code so I can begin conceptualising my task.

[train function source code.](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/pkg/caret/R/train.default.R)
[trainControl function source code.](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/pkg/caret/R/trainControl.R)

Again, I appreciate this is not a code specific problem and therefore not looking for an extensive answer. Just some guidance.

Comment: I don't really understand what you intend to do (include your validation data in the model building process? Don't do that!), but it should be easier to write your own function than modifying the package function.

Comment: I just intend in supplying the hold out samples from an already prepped validation set instead of splitting the training set into 2 parts. If that makes sense